# PHP - Send form itself between pages

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have a web site with several php pages, one of them (called form.php for instance) prints with `echo` a form which action is sending the form itself with `action=$_POST[PHP_SELF]`, the problem I have is due to security my web site is an `Index.php` page with another page `include`,another one and another one which is `form.php`.

When I click "submit" on the form the "submit" goes to Index, not to `form.php`, how can I solve that ? If I use the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` in the index works fine but with different results, I want this to work in the `form.php` page, let's say I just want to run a function, add data to mysql and show a sentence saying `done`, I do everything, but going through `index.php` and including the form.php again.

Any help ? thanks in advanced.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your problem. `include` will have no effect since it's only spitting out all the code of that file. You should know that even though you are including `form.php` with `action=$_POST[PHP_SELF]` the page that's displaying it is `index.php` so this will be your `$_POST[PHP_SELF]`.

Comment: Yes, but when I include a php...shows information ( from mysql ).So If I call index.php shows the code...and calling it again with the isset...shows the code in form.php twice.

Comment: use **[include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)**

Comment: I think my web site it's more complicate than that, hehe. Include_once fixes the problem showing in code twice, but not in the right way.

Comment: I think it's a problem with the way you are calling it. Some code will help.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier sending a form in a php page to save info to mysql...but not with a form ? I'm already connected to the server cause I'm in the php file...but..how to get the form fields values ?

Comment: Using the `name` property of the input fields. Example if your input field is like: `<input type="text" name="field1">` you would access it with `$_POST['field1']`

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger You mean without the submit or submit the form with action="" ? How about if I use a button onclick to store this fields with $_POST['field1'] as you said ?

Comment: action="" would submit it to the index.php page. Where is the submission code located? And you cannot get the posted values like that by button click, the form HAS to be submitted.

Comment: Ok, how about if I just want to keep the fields values from a form to send it to a php function to save this to a mysql ? calling a javascript function ? I really don't need the form to do nothing, just need the form fields values for the database.

Comment: Well, don't know if it's the best solution ever but I fix it whithout a form.

I just create some fields ( like a form ), with names and a button to a javascript function, this function gets the fields value with document.getElementById('field').value and then call a php file passing the values to process the information ( save to mysql ).

Thanks @ICanHasCheezburger for your help.  :)

Comment: So you have used ajax. Glad you got it working somehow.